# Big data: 3D clustering with over 40 groups

Tags: 3d, clustering

I am a computational neuroscientist and I struggling over a problem; I have around one hundred 3D matrices (I am working on MATLAB at the moment), each of them is 121x145x121. Any 'cell' stores a value between 0 and 1, e.g. Y(90,60,30) = 0.4486. To give you some context all the matrices are MRI scans. Now, I need to cluster these 'cells' into ~48 groups so that all the cells in a cluster are more correlated (Pearson coefficient) with themselves than with the rest of the cells (among all the scans).

I can try to give you an example with 2D matrices:

$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
0& 0& 0\\
0& 1 &1\\
0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix},\quad\quad $
$B =\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& 0\\
0 &2 &2\\
0 &0& 0\end{bmatrix},\quad\quad$$C =\begin{bmatrix}
0& 0& 0\\
0 &3& 3\\
0 &0& 0
\end{bmatrix}.$

In this case with 2 clusters I will have something like:

$C_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 1\\
1 &0& 0\\
1& 1& 1
\end{bmatrix},\quad\quad$$
C_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& 0\\
0& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}.$

Of course here the real problem is the huge amount of data to be processed. All the algorithm I tried failed. Maybe you can help me to look at the problem from a different point of view.